# Angular Observable updates value inside component but UI is never updated

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to add a ngClass for a button based on the value returned by a state observable but the HTML value only changes once (I think) or the update happens to fast.

Basically what I'm doing is this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testSubscription = this.cartStore
      .pipe(select(CartSelectors.canCheckout))
      .subscribe((canCheckout) => {
        this.testCanCheckout = canCheckout;
        console.log('Can checkout', this.testCanCheckout);
      });
  }
```

And I've also tried to get the selector mapped to an Observable like this:

```
this.canUserCheckout$ = this.cartStore.pipe(
  select(CartSelectors.canCheckout)
);
```

And then in the UI, I have this to test if the values are ever getting updated or not:

```
        <p>{{ canUserCheckout$ | async }}</p>
        <p>{{ testCanCheckout }}</p>
        <up-pos-action-button
          [ngClass]="{ 'div-disabled': !(canUserCheckout$ | async) }"
          *ngIf="
            (selectedOpenTable$ | async) && (cartProductCount$ | async) > 0
          "
          (click)="sendCartToTable()"
          [@slideUpDown]
        >
          <div class="button-icon">
            <fa-icon class="text-4xl text-white" [icon]="['fal', 'hat-chef']">
            </fa-icon>
          </div>
          <div class="button-label">
            {{ 'Send' | uppercase }}
          </div>
        </up-pos-action-button>
```

Both `<p>{{ canUserCheckout$ | async }}</p>` and  `<p>{{ testCanCheckout }}</p>` are always false even tho the console logs look like this:

```
state.logger.ts:6 [Product] Load Product
state.logger.ts:6 [Auth] Reset Logout Timer
state.logger.ts:6 [Product] Load Product Success
state.logger.ts:6 [Product] Add Cart Product Directly To Cart
state.logger.ts:6 [Pos Cart] Add Product
```

> web-pos-layout.component.ts:269 Can checkout false

```
state.logger.ts:6 [Pos Cart] Add Product Success
```

> ```
> web-pos-layout.component.ts:269 Can checkout true
> ```

```
state.logger.ts:6 [Cart] Update Cart Total
state.logger.ts:6 [Product] Dismiss Product Modifier Dialog
state.logger.ts:6 [Web Kiosk Modal] Close Modal
state.logger.ts:6 [Cart] Deselect Cart Product
```

Here is the component that does the logic. Maybe there is something wrong with the change detection but I could not figure it out.

```
import { Component, Inject, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterState } from '@angular/router';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { CartSelectors } from '@up/web-cart-state';
import { combineLatest, Observable, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'up-web-pos-layout',
  templateUrl: './web-pos-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./web-pos-layout.component.scss'],
  animations: [slideUpDown, slideDownUp]
})
export class WebPosLayoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  canUserCheckout$: Observable<boolean>;
  testSubscription: Subscription;

  testCanCheckout = true;

  constructor(private cartStore: Store<CartFeature.CartPartialState>) {
    this.canUserCheckout$ = this.cartStore.pipe(
      select(CartSelectors.canCheckout)
    );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.testSubscription = this.cartStore
      .pipe(select(CartSelectors.canCheckout))
      .subscribe((canCheckout) => {
        this.testCanCheckout = canCheckout;
        console.log('Can checkout', this.testCanCheckout);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    this.testSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using this component as a router endpoint? Or it is inside the HTML of another one like that <up-web-pos-layout></up-web-pos-layout>? If it is inside the HTML of another one then it is possible his parent to have "changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush". Which means that the view is going to be rerendered only on @Input/@Output parameters changed.

Comment: This is the HTML of the parent component:
`<up-web-pos-layout oncontextmenu="return false;">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</up-web-pos-layout>`

Comment: And the parent component does not have the changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: Then please try to select like that: this.canUserCheckout$ = this.cartStore.select(CartSelectors.canCheckout);

Comment: Maybe your template is not connected to the component class properly?